# If any columns are null return an empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a blanket statement you can use in a SQL query that allows all columns if `NULL` to return an empty string instead of `NULL`?

At the moment I am doing a `CASE` per column, for example:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHERE column_name IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE column_name
    END
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: `coalesce(column_name,'')` - but its always on a column only basis - nothing blanket available. Many client side access libraries (e.g. ADO.NET) are able to convert null to a blank string however.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks dale, unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem for ALL columns in a single query. I have rephrased my question slightly.

Comment: No I realise that, I did understand your question, there is no other solution - but `coalesce` is shorter than a case expression, and you can use `isnull` for even less typing, its just not ANSI SQL.

Comment: Not all NULLs can be implicitly converted to '' string. For instance DATE/UNIQUEIDENTIFIER/INT. You should consider handling it at presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in column level using COALESCE or ISNULL. But, if you want to for all columns together, I am suggesting a workaround.

Copy the data into a table with default value as EmptyString. If you dont want physical table, you can think of temporary tables also.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableCopy
(
Col1 INT NULL = '',
Col2 INT NULL =''
.
.
)
```

Now, you load data into the above table.

```sql
INSERT INTO Tablecopy
SELECT * FROM OriginalTable
```

Now, if you select data from Tablecopy, all NULLs will be replaced with '', as default values are replacing NULL input

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableCopy
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid column type constraint checking, the column should be converted into string/varchar. So the new column only present a varchar type.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN column_name IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(255))
    END AS new_column_name
FROM TABLE
```

**EDIT**

Otherwise you can use concat_ws function to concat or join two or more column values with separator. If it receives arguments with all NULL values, then it will return an empty string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', column_name1, column_name2, ..) AS value FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Unsure if you read the question. I want to do this for all columns. Is there a single statement that will convert all null results in all columns to strings?

Comment: I understand what you wants. I have edit my answer. You can use CONCAT_WS function for that purpose, and make any proper adjustment if you wants.